Number of elements in $[3^{j-1},3^j]$ which are divisible by $3$ but not $3^2$
I want to calculate for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ the number of elements in $[3^{j-1},3^j]$ which are divisible by $3$ but not $3^2$. To this end, denote by $f$ the map, which maps $[3^{j-1},3^j]$ to said number and $g$ the map, which maps $[3^{j-1},3^j]$ to the number of elements in $[3^{j-1},3^j]$ which are not at all divisible by $3$. It is clear, that
$$f([3^{j-1},3^j])=g([3^{j-2},3^{j-1}])$$
which leads to the question about recurrsions on $g([3^{j-1},3^j])$ in $j$. Initial conditions are given by $g([1,3])=2$, and $g([3^{j-1},3^j])$ is given by all elements in the intervall, except those which have "ancestors" in $g([3^{k-1},3^{k}])$ for some $k<j$, meaning, they have been counted before by $f$ or $g$ for some $k<j$. Consequently, $g([3^{j-1},3^{j}])$ satisfies
$$g([3^{j-1},3^{j}])=3^j-3^{j-1}+1-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}f([3^{j-1},3^{j}])+g([3^{j-1},3^{j}])\right).$$
Plugging in the first condition and moving around some indices, this gives the recurrsion
$$g([3^{j-1},3^{j}])=3^j-3^{j-1}+1-\left(g([3^{j-2},3^{j-1}])+2\sum_{k=1}^{j-2}g([3^{k-1},3^{k}])\right)$$
or shortened
$$g_j=3^j-3^{j-1}+1-(g_{j-1}+2\sum_{k=1}^{j-2} g_k)$$
with initial condition $g_1=2$. So far so good, but is there a closed form solution for this? I would like to make an asymptotic statement about $f([3^{j-1},3^j])/(3^j-3^{j-1})$ for $j\to\infty$ to make a claim about the density of such numbers over $\mathbb{N}$. Does anyone know a closed form solution here?

Why so complicated? For $n\ge 2$, in the interval $[1,3^n]$ you have $3^{n-1}$ numbers divisible by $3$ and $3^{n-2}$ numbers divisible by $9$

Use Andrei's observation to calculate the answer for $n=j$ and also for $n=j-1$ and subtract.

@KeithBackman thank you, just saw that and deleted my comment

Also note that the answer for $j=2$ will have an additional $+1$ that all the other $j$ does not have.
